# Mobile Safari iOS 6.0 fixed positioning while keyboard showing

Tags: iphone, css, ios, mobile, safari

If you have a fixed position div set to the bottom of the screen, this div does not stay at the bottom while the virtual keyboard is shown. It would move up as the height of the page increases. This problem does not occur in iOS 5 as the div continues to stay at the bottom like it should. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply hide the fixed div while the keyboard is active?

```
$("#text_field").focus(function(){
  $("#fixed_div").hide();
});


$("#text_field").blur(function(){
  $("#fixed_div").show();
});
```