# issue with iOS fixed position css

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 5 fixed positioning and virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970389/ios-5-fixed-positioning-and-virtual-keyboard)

Has anyone come across this before? It only happens when the keyboard is on screen, once the keyboard is hidden again it goes back to normal.

The CSS

```
div#menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-account" class="active"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li id="menu-readmeter"><a href="#">Read Meter</a></li>
        <li id="menu-info"><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        <li id="menu-logout"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        <br class="clear">
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: App]

Comment: My solution to this issue was to hide the `div#menu` when a form element had focus and then show it when the form element lost focus.