# Fixed footer with input breaks with virtual keyword iOS 9 / Safari

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I have a fixed footer which contains a subscription form. When I focus the input the window scrolls where it is placed in the DOM (order below the content).

[image]

I have tried several options without any solution:

- [iOS 5 fixed positioning and virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970389/ios-5-fixed-positioning-and-virtual-keyboard)
- [iOS iPad Fixed position breaks when keyboard is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492613/ios-ipad-fixed-position-breaks-when-keyboard-is-opened)

I just want the form stay at the top of the keyboard and the current scroll position to maintain.

And more. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't I end up creating 2 versions with media queries, if it's touch I show the "not fixed version" and if not, I show. That's the way I detect the possibility of virtual keyboard.