# Bind events to all text input fields in all Backbone views

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, mobile-safari, backbone-views

I am looking for a way to create global bindings that will span all views within the app, so that I do not have to set up these within each view individually.

Bonus points if suggested mechanism has a way for individual input fields or views to opt out from this behaviour.

---

Details:

I've encountered this error where the virtual keyboard causes a div with `positioned: fixed;` (the header) to be positioned oddly on the screen, and then be repositioned correctly once more when the keyboard is hidden; I have chosen to solve this using a solution similar to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15537846/194982

Now, it is possible to apply this to all text input elements individually like so:

```
events: {
    'blur input#myInputText': '_myInputTextBlur',
    'focus input#myInputText': '_myInputTextFocus'
},
_myInputTextBlur: function() { console.error('_myInputTextBlur');
    $('.page-header').css('display', 'block')
},
_myInputTextFocus: function() { console.error('_myInputTextFocus');
    $('.page-header').css('display', 'none')
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I wrote my tipp in coffe script because it is simpler.

You can use a mechanism similar to ruby mixins. Then create a mixin with your common behaviour. Then mix the concern into a class which extends Backbone.View. Then use your base view class in all places as base for your view classes.

This is the mixesIn [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function:

```
_.mixin
  mixesIn: (base, mixins...) ->
    class Mixed extends base
    for mixin in mixins by -1
      for name, method of mixin::
        Mixed::[name] = method
    Mixed
```

This is your concern:

```
class InputSupport
  events:
    "blur input#myInputText": "_myInputTextBlur"
    "focus input#myInputText": "_myInputTextFocus"

  _myInputTextBlur = ->
    console.error "_myInputTextBlur"
    $(".page-header").css "display", "block"

  _myInputTextFocus = ->
    console.error "_myInputTextFocus"
    $(".page-header").css "display", "none"
```

This will be your BaseView class:

```
  class BaseView extends _(Backbone.View).mixesIn InputSupport
```

Then in each of you specialized view classes you can extend from BaseView class.

```
class HeaderView extends BaseView
...
class SidebarView extends BaseView
...
class FooterView extends BaseView
  events:
    "blur input#myInputText": "_myInputTextBlur"
    "focus input#myInputText": "_myInputTextFocus"
    "click .someotheButton": 'handleSomeOtherButton'
```

In the last case you need repeat the events declared in the concern unless you write a more intelligent mixesIn function which merges the two hash... That can be done with [_.defaults](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) function easily but in that case you will face a problem with the substraction of events in your descendant classes which will be a smell.