# Fixed bootstrap nav floats on ipad when input field is selected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ios7, safari

Bootstrap v3.1.1,

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

If in Safari in iOS7 you select one of the input fields in the top nav so the keyboard opens, then scroll down on the page the page, the nav will scroll also.

If you scroll down the page a little then do the same as above, the nav jumps into the middle of the page. See screenshot.

Closing the keyboard fixes this, is there any work around for this? Or is it a iPad restriction or what?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this and see if it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970389/ios-5-fixed-positioning-and-virtual-keyboard